# Using an ipywidget dropdown in Jupyter Notebook to declare a variable and carry it forward to future cells - only working if i run one cell at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, dropdown, ipywidgets

I feel like this should not be difficult to resolve, but I am struggling nonetheless... I have a jupyter notebook which I am using to pull specific data from a SQL database based on some user inputs. This notebook has worked great for myself and coworkers using input boxes, however the inputs we use are quite long, so my team would love if I could provide dropdown selection boxes in place of the manual inputs. I am providing a sample of my code below, but here is the core of my issue:
When I run my notebook one cell at a time manually, I get to the cell with the dropdown, choose the selection I want, then continue to the next cell and it stores the variable correctly. HOWEVER, when I try to run the entire notebook at once, the dropdown stores the first option in the list and continues to the next cell. Even if I try putting a "hit enter to continue" in the same cell as the dropdown, it will still only record the top list option and not whichever item the user selected. I have been playing around with global variables and different forms of on_change functionality, but nothing is working. Please help.

**Here is my original code:**

(Cell 1)

```
#DB_List = A, B, C, D, E (this is not part of the code, just for reference)

print("Input the CURRENT Quarter Exposure DB Name: ")
Selection = widgets.Dropdown(
                options=DB_List,
                layout={'width':'max-content'},
                description='DB: ',
                disabled=False)

display (Selection)
```

```
Dropdown Box Selections Provided: A, B, C, D, E
```

(Cell 2)

```
Final_DB = Selection.value
print(Final_DB)
```

```
*Result: *A (Even when I select B, C, D, E etc. I am provided with A as the result. UNLESS I run cell 1, change the selection, and manually run cell 2 after that)
```

**Here is the most recent code I have tried, still to no avail:**

```
Selection = widgets.Dropdown(
                options=DB_List,
                layout={'width':'max-content'},
                description='DB: ',
                disabled=False)

def on_change(change):
    global Final_DB
    print(change.new)
    Final_DB = change.new
Selection.observe(on_change, names='value')
display (Selection)

input ("Make selection and press Enter to continue...")

Final_DB = ExposureSelection.value
print(Final_DB)
```

Comment: Several things. Your code provided isn't close to being complete. Provide minimal reproducible code. This seems like an XY problem. You seem to want to make a webapp that steps users through setting things with ipywidgets. Instead of doing that you are thinking separate cells will do it. And that could work. What is wrong with the run all behaving as it does? It will be quickly testable that way allowing easy development by you. Just tell your users not to do that unless they want the defaults? If you want an app, make that. It seems you are setting us up for any suggestion to not be quite ...

Comment: <continued> what you want because you aren't developing this as it probably should be. Why not set them using `interacctive()` and/or in one cell, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74829153/8508004)? There's a related, expanded example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74861254/8508004). And [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/select-widget-select-none-possible-or-distinguish-user-interaction-value-change/16370) proposes setting the default to `-` so that you can insure user interaction. That last option may be preferable and could work with multiple cells, I think.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Wayne well thanks you for your honesty... I do not know how to create an app, I was under the impression that I could get all the code written and then work on building out an app. I will take a look at the links you have provided, however I feel like this issue should be easily replicable with how its written. It's essentially a dropdown that, when selected, should pass the selection to a variable that is used later in the code. The only issue is that the code is passing the first option on the list instead of what the user selected. I will let you know if I am successful using the links

Comment: You can create an app from an `ipynb` file using [Voila](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or Voici. (The latter being very early in development and not recommended unless you are using close to pure Python or not much else besidse Pandas and numpy, other words aren't using any fancy network stuff. There's also [Appmode](https://github.com/oschuett/appmode) which is simpler & predates Voila; however, I don't know how well it supports recent Jupyter tech. If you aren't doing an app, I don't see why you cannot just say at the top of the notebook what will happen if you use 'Run All'.

Comment: Minor aside: "however I feel like this issue should be easily replicable with how its written." Point is we shouldn't have to put effort into rounding out what you provided to make it work. Help those trying to help you. You have working code so you could provide it in your post. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) clearly spells out you want to 'Help others reproduce the problem' as it has a subheading emphasizing that and the first bullet point is a guide to creating a minimial reproducible example.

Comment: So far I have not found a perfect solution. Each link provided by Wayne seemed to get me close, but I am not able to run the entire notebook at once while passing along the dropdown selections as variables. For now, I will instruct my coworkers to run each cell separately and I will have to look into creating an app at a later date. I would be open to creating this code in a different program like pycharm, etc, but im not sure the actual results will be different. It still seems I need a stopping point at the dropdown selection chunk of the code.

Comment: @Wayne, I really appreciate the help, however I am not really sure what it is that I did not provide? I pasted in the code using A, B, C, D as the variables. This is private information, so I am not able to share the EXACT code that I am working with. I provided what I could, and if placed within any blank jupyter notebook, all that is needed that I did not provide is to create teh A, B, C, D dataframe and import pandas / ipywidgets. If that wasn't clear, then my apologies, hopefully others reading this will see this comment and have the gaps filled in.

Comment: I understand you concern about not using the actual code. However, you can create toy examples that parallel your effort and include them in a way they'd work. If you make a toy example that gets closer to your issue, you will get back more specific solutions that will be pertinent to your use case. This is just general advice for here. Only a guide. I pointed out it was a minor thing. Don't worry too much about it. I'm more concerned that this is rather broad question when you get down to it. And I should have pointed out that Voila is based on ipywidgets. It will only really render them ...

Comment: <continued> and so it forces you to be more thorough in development because you'll see adding things like `input()` isn't going to handle what you need.