# Options in ipywidgets combobox displaying multiple times

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am trying to make a simple UI where a user enters text into a combobox and based on their input the options are updated. This works but the options display multiple times. Here is the callback function

```
def textInput(deckID, quantity, current_db, val):
    if not db_file.closed:
        openFile(None)
    foundOne, data = searchScryfall(val.new)
    if(data):
        if(not foundOne):
            options = [x['name'] for x in data]
            combo.options = options
        else:
            current_db[deckID]
```

The result looks like this

[image: Redundant options]

Is there some way to reset to tell ipywidgets that the options have changed and not to just append a new list?

Comment: From the little, **incomplete** code you've shared and the screenshot that doesn't seem to show what you discuss, it is hard to say. It would be preferable to have code that shows what you describe even if it is toy code such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74829153/8508004) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74861254/8508004). Please see the section entitled 'Help others reproduce the problem' in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where it discusses a minimal, reproducible example.